# Javascript: Issue with && statement not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to allow users to click within `.dropdown-content` and the menu remains open. However, I also need to leave the `.dropbtn` available to click otherwise they cannot open the menu.

I originally attempting to use `||` in the following code: `!e.target.matches('.dropbtn') || !e.target.matches('.dropdown-content')`.

After a discussion in the comments I was informed that I should be using `&&`. I updated that section of code and still had some issues with getting the code to work properly. The snippet has been updated below.

Below you can see the area that I believe the focus should be. I am gathering all of the sections that would need to toggle between active and non-active states. Then trying to validate the following:

1. While a user is within `.dropdown-content` or any of its children it *should not* close.
2. Once the user clicks outside of the drop down button or `.dropdown-content` (not including DIVs that reside within it, aka. children) the menu *should* close.

**Problem Area:**

```
var ourCompany = document.getElementById("our-company");
var services = document.getElementById("services");
var products = document.getElementById("products");
var resources = document.getElementById("resources");
var goTo = document.getElementById("go-to");

// Close the dropdown(s) if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function (e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn') && !e.target.matches('.dropdown-content')) {
        ourCompany.classList.remove('active-drop');
        services.classList.remove('active-drop');
        products.classList.remove('active-drop');
        resources.classList.remove('active-drop');
        goTo.classList.remove('active-drop');
    }
}
```

**Code:**

```js
/* Navigation Scroll */
var startPos = -1;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var bar = document.getElementById('pm-nav');
  var ourCompany = document.getElementById("our-company");
  var services = document.getElementById("services");
  var products = document.getElementById("products");
  var resources = document.getElementById("resources");
  var goTo = document.getElementById("go-to");

  if (startPos < 0) startPos = findPosY(bar);

  if (pageYOffset > startPos) {
    bar.style.position = 'fixed';
    bar.style.top = 0;

    ourCompany.classList.add("dropdown-content-scroll");
    services.classList.add("dropdown-content-scroll");
    products.classList.add("dropdown-content-scroll");
    resources.classList.add("dropdown-content-scroll");
    goTo.classList.add("dropdown-content-scroll");

  } else {
    bar.style.position = 'relative';

    ourCompany.classList.remove('dropdown-content-scroll');
    services.classList.remove('dropdown-content-scroll');
    products.classList.remove('dropdown-content-scroll');
    resources.classList.remove('dropdown-content-scroll');
    goTo.classList.remove('dropdown-content-scroll');
  }

};

function findPosY(obj) {
  var curtop = 0;
  if (typeof(obj.offsetParent) != 'undefined' && obj.offsetParent) {
    while (obj.offsetParent) {
      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
      obj = obj.offsetParent;
    }
    curtop += obj.offsetTop;
  } else if (obj.y)
    curtop += obj.y;
  return curtop;
}

/* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown(s) content */
function toggleDrop(drop) {

  var i = 0;
  while (i < 5) {
    document.getElementById(document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[i].id).classList.remove('active-drop');
    i++;
  }

  switch (drop) {

    case "our-company":

      document.getElementById("our-company").classList.add("active-drop");
      break;

    case "services":

      document.getElementById("services").classList.add("active-drop");
      break;

    case "products":

      document.getElementById("products").classList.add("active-drop");
      break;

    case "resources":

      document.getElementById("resources").classList.add("active-drop");
      break;

    case "go-to":

      document.getElementById("go-to").classList.add("active-drop");
      break;

    default:

      //make this unknown...
  }
}

var ourCompany = document.getElementById("our-company");
var services = document.getElementById("services");
var products = document.getElementById("products");
var resources = document.getElementById("resources");
var goTo = document.getElementById("go-to");

// Close the dropdown(s) if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn') && !e.target.matches('.dropdown-content')) {
    ourCompany.classList.remove('active-drop');
    services.classList.remove('active-drop');
    products.classList.remove('active-drop');
    resources.classList.remove('active-drop');
    goTo.classList.remove('active-drop');
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.paymaster.com/net4/css/pm-main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Website Header -->
<header class="pm-mainHeader">
  <div class="maxWidth-1440">This is a Header</div>
</header>
<!-- Website header :END -->

<!-- Website Navigation -->
<div id="pm-nav" class="pm-mainNav">
  <div class="maxWidth-1440">
    <div class="pm-row pm-box-sizing">
      <div class="dropdown pm-col-5">
        <button onclick="toggleDrop('our-company');return false;" class="dropbtn">Our Company</button>
        <div id="our-company" class="dropdown-content">
          <div class="pm-row">
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 1</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 2</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 3</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mFooter redBg">
            <h2>Menu our-company</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown pm-col-5">
        <button onclick="toggleDrop('services');return false;" class="dropbtn">Services</button>
        <div id="services" class="dropdown-content">
          <div class="pm-row">
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 4</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 5</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 6</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mFooter blueBg">
            <h2>Menu services</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown pm-col-5">
        <button onclick="toggleDrop('products');return false;" class="dropbtn">Products</button>
        <div id="products" class="dropdown-content">
          <div class="pm-row">
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 1</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 2</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 3</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mFooter greenBg">
            <h2>Menu products</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown pm-col-5">
        <button onclick="toggleDrop('resources');return false;" class="dropbtn">Resources</button>
        <div id="resources" class="dropdown-content">
          <div class="pm-row">
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 1</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 2</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 3</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mFooter orangeBg">
            <h2>Menu resources</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown pm-col-5">
        <button onclick="toggleDrop('go-to');return false;" class="dropbtn">Go To</button>
        <div id="go-to" class="dropdown-content">
          <div class="pm-row">
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 1</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 2</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
              <h3>Category 3</h3>
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mFooter purpleBg">
            <div class="closeBtnContainer">
              <span class="closeBtn"><i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_up</i><i class="material-icons">menu</i></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Website Navigation :END -->

<!-- Main Content -->
<div style="padding: 300px;">Test</div>
<!-- Main Content :END -->

<!-- Main Footer -->
<footer class="pm-mainFooter">
  <div class="maxWidth-1440">This is a Footer</div>
</footer>
<!-- Main Footer :END -->
```

Comment: Fix your `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null",` errors first.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, it sounds like you need `&&` instead. You want the first condition to be true when both matches are false?

Comment: I dont have that error on the site

Comment: @RickSibley there is no HTML in your snippet thus causing the error.

Comment: Your condition is like `not X or not Y` so it is always true.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried that earlier but it would still close the menu. Ill double check it now. ty

Comment: You must post enough code so that we can reproduce your issue. You haven't posted the required HTML for us to do that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the site is updated with `&&` and it still closing the menu

Comment: @ScottMarcus click the link... I would need to attach so much code in order for the menu to display so i figured it would be way easier to just go to the live site and use the inspector.

Comment: @RickSibley && seems like it should be correct. I suspect your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: The only link in your question is the one within your code snippet. Clicking that causes errors.

Comment: @ScottMarcus https://www.paymaster.com/net4/

Comment: Side note, you don't need all those `if (resources.classList.contains('active-drop')) {` checks. Just remove the class. If it's not already there, no harm is done.

Comment: And put your elements in an array, and it's just `elems.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("active-drop"))`

Comment: @rockstar thanks for the advice. im working on that now

Comment: @rockstar im trying to understand the `elems.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("active-drop"))` part of your comment. Am I supposed to be doing `var elems = [document.getElementById("our-company"), document.getElementById("services"), document.getElementById("products"), document.getElementById("resources"), document.getElementById("go-to")];` ?

Comment: @RickSibley: Yes, that will put all the elements into an array. So then the `.forEach()` just iterates the array, invoking the callback for each item. The callback uses the new arrow function syntax. You can use a traditional function to support legacy browsers. `elems.forEach(function(el) { el.classList.remove("active-drop") })`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/58564w4n/

Comment: @rockstar thanks man, I was pretty close but after seeing how you used it I noticed my error. I'm going to start implementing this more often. thank you for your time and knowledge!

Comment: I also figured out why the menu was still closing even when I put the `&&`. It needed to be `!e.target.matches('.dropbtn') && !e.target.matches('.dropdown-content *')` (added `*` to the end of `.dropdown-content`)

Comment: Cool, glad you got it all worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a lot of hate during the start of this question but I'm thankful for those who stuck around and helped out. The combination of different inputs lead me to figure out what the issue was, it was very simple, adding `*` to the end of `.dropdown-content`. Adding `*` tells the code to look at `.dropdown-content` and all of its children.

One of the original issue was solved by @Carcigenicate, they informed me I was using `||` instead of `&&` combining this information with the data above lead me to the answer I was seeking, but my code was still not efficient. So, @rockstar pointed out some key things I could do to help improve my code and is responsible for half of the answer. Thanks again man!

Thanks everyone for the help, without further ado here is the...

**ANSWER:**

```
var elems = [
  document.getElementById("our-company"),
  document.getElementById("services"),
  document.getElementById("products"),
  document.getElementById("resources"),
  document.getElementById("go-to")
];

window.onclick = function (e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn') && !e.target.matches('.dropdown-content *')) {
        elems.forEach(function (el) {
            el.classList.remove("active-drop");
        })
    }
}
```